# Data not receiving from web server using url connection and async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, urlconnection

I have some data in a web server in a link: http://tonyjoseph.site90.com/demo/ Now I need to get this data received into my android using url connection. I have given some code in the async task. The code is given below:

```
String link18="http://tonyjoseph.site90.com/demo/";
URL url18 = new URL(link18);
URLConnection conn18 = url18.openConnection();
conn18.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr18 = new OutputStreamWriter (conn18.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader reader18 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(conn18.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb18=new StringBuilder();
String line18 = null;
while((line18 = reader18.readLine()) !=null)
{
    sb18.append(line18);
    break;
}
status18=sb18.toString();
Log.d("Status 18",status18);// Nothing displayed in logcat even the Status18 tag is not displayed in log
System.out.println(status18); // Here also System.out.println tag is not displayed in logcat.
```

But the problem is that I'm getting null value in the String status18. After calling this code in the doinBackground of async task. When I tried to toast the value also, It is showing an empty toast.

So can someone please help me out by correcting the code if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention which language you are using to connect between android and server 
 
Assuming that you are using Jason, follow the code below:

```
try{
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yourwebsiteAdrress");
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();
                        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
                }
                     catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
                        showToast("Connect to the internet");}


                    try
                     {
                         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                             sb.append(line + "\n");
                         }
                         is.close();
                         result = sb.toString();
                    Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");

                }
                     catch(Exception e)
                     {Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());}



                    try
                    {
                            //to receive web page information
                             JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                             Yourjsonmessage=(json_data.getInt("code")); 


         // in my case the information is error message so I wanted to print it to the user                                
                     if(!"".equals( Yourjsonmessage))
                     {
                      showToast( Yourjsonmessage);
                     }
                     else if 
                     {
                        showToast("done!");

                     }
```